# Solutions of $x'(t) = f(t)g(x(t))$ are of the form $x(t) = ψ(φ(t) -c)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

*Let the differential equation :*

$$x' = f(t)g(x) = F(t,x)$$

*where $x=x(t)$ is an unknown real scalar function and $F$,$\partial F/\partial x$ are continuous in $B=\{(t,x) : t_1 < t < t_2, a < x < b \}$. We suppose that $g(x) \neq 0,\forall x \in (a,b).$ Let $u=φ(t)$ be a solution of $u'=f(t)$ and $x=ψ(u)$ a solution of $x'(u) = g(x)$. Show that all the solutions of $x'=F(t,x)$ are described by the family $x(t) = ψ(φ(t)-c)$, where the constant $c$ varies depending on the initial values.*

Now, I do not even know how to start/proceed with this problem, this is the reason I cannot provide any attempt. I would appreciate any hint or even more a thorough solution/help.

Comment: What does it mean to say $x$ is an unknown real step function? Is this an exact transcription of the problem?

Comment: @copper.hat The problem is written in Greek and I miss-interpreted that part. The correct is : " $x$  is an unknown real **scalar** function ". Thanks for your remark and I edited it above !

Comment: Note that $\phi'(t) = f(t)$ and $\psi'(u) = g(\psi(u))$. if you let $x(t)= \psi(\phi(t)-c)$ and find $x'$ using the chain rule you will see that $x$ satisfies the differential equation. The conditions on $F$ give uniqueness (for a particular initial condition).